# Hexadecimal value arranged in memory for a little‐endian/big-endian?

Tags: mips, endianness

For the hexadecimal value 0×3dc49e73 that is stored at address 0;

a ) How would it be arranged in memory for a little‐endian machine?

b ) How about a big‐endian machine?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Yes, i don't get how to explain this.

Comment: Is it just 3d-c4-9e-73 for big endian and 73-9e-c4-3d for little endian?

Answer (score 0):

It helps to know that hex is base 16, decimal is base 10, and binary is base 2.

hexidecimal maps nicely to bytes because it uses a power of 2.  every character pair = 1 byte (8 bits)

So if you break up your hex value, you have 4 bytes: 3d c4 9e 73.

They will be stored in that order for big endian, and reverse for little endian.